# How are truthy and falsey implemented in flow control?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
name = ''
while True:
    Print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Your name':
        break
print('Thank you')
```

If empty strings and 0s are falsey values, while others are truthy falues. Why is the "while" loop set to "True" with an empty strings and the code ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why the loop started when `name` was set to an empty string (falsey), it's because the loop itself doesn't *care* about `name`.

It's using `True`, which is, well, pretty much *always* true :-)

The loop is therefore an infinite one and the only way out of it is via the `break` statement that fires if the name you enter matches the string in the `if` statement.

If you instead had something like:

```
name = ''
while name:
    blahBlahBlah()
```

then the loop would not start because the empty string is considered false.

Comment: Haha! I get it now. Thank you!